# Google Places Autocomplete returns place_id linked to erroneous place

Tags: google-places-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?language=fr&input=5+avenue+de+l%27union+p&radius=50000&location=48.2%2C2.3

This call returns among others:

```
{
    'description': u "5 Avenue de l'Union, Paray-Vieille-Poste, France",
    'place_id': 'EjA1IEF2ZW51ZSBkZSBsJ1VuaW9uLCBQYXJheS1WaWVpbGxlLVBvc3RlLCBGcmFuY2U',
    'id': '0762652b32b4b27a6be6c89d706c1e1279073e9f',
...
}
```

Then, when requesting the place details

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EjA1IEF2ZW51ZSBkZSBsJ1VuaW9uLCBQYXJheS1WaWVpbGxlLVBvc3RlLCBGcmFuY2U

It returns a 
place which is not the one expected. Apparently a confusion with a the same street name in another city ("Juvisy" vs "Paray-Vieille-Poste") :

```js
 {
     'status': 'OK',
     'html_attributions': [],
     'result': {
         'utc_offset': 60,
         'name': u "5 Avenue de l'Union",
         'reference': 'CpQBkAAAAKfctAfslcVNWK_kGk6gzecawbnBT8JD5Tchnyheh0SyULvlV6XlyZpjkExmykkL3_2lvm5ZoHRAxqO7GPra2vt11osAzE2RJdcT7Fc7c069IpHgvsdJpmNvWb3FjMIrn092DmQj-GKlfAmA9pvvAw6zyKJfd1XQFK88Kl09CULdpxM9vMb-AIfHhGwUe6KP7RIQ2r3XA3Xjax5iCDWbuiZqNBoUqy-PYeUYY9xA_I65wZjdQLQXsVE',
         'geometry': {
             'location': {
                 'lat': 48.69058269999999,
                 'lng': 2.3692054
             },
             'viewport': {
                 'northeast': {
                     'lat': 48.6919374802915,
                     'lng': 2.370557630291501
                 },
                 'southwest': {
                     'lat': 48.6892395197085,
                     'lng': 2.367859669708498
                 }
             }
         },
         'adr_address': '<span class="street-address">5 Avenue de l&#39;Union</span>, <span class="postal-code">91260</span> <span class="locality">Juvisy-sur-Orge</span>, <span class="country-name">France</span>',
         'place_id': 'EjI1IEF2ZW51ZSBkZSBsJ1VuaW9uLCA5MTI2MCBKdXZpc3ktc3VyLU9yZ2UsIEZyYW5jZQ',
         'vicinity': 'Juvisy-sur-Orge',
         'url': 'https://maps.google.com/?q=5+Avenue+de+l%27Union,+91260+Juvisy-sur-Orge,+France&ftid=0x47e5df5943bfe633:0x24dc923a0494f142',
         'scope': 'GOOGLE',
         'address_components': [{
             'long_name': '5',
             'types': ['street_number'],
             'short_name': '5'
         }, {
             'long_name': u "Avenue de l'Union",
             'types': ['route'],
             'short_name': u "Avenue de l'Union"
         }, {
             'long_name': 'Juvisy-sur-Orge',
             'types': ['locality', 'political'],
             'short_name': 'Juvisy-sur-Orge'
         }, {
             'long_name': 'Essonne',
             'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'],
             'short_name': 'Essonne'
         }, {
             'long_name': '\xcele-de-France',
             'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'],
             'short_name': '\xcele-de-France'
         }, {
             'long_name': 'France',
             'types': ['country', 'political'],
             'short_name': 'FR'
         }, {
             'long_name': '91260',
             'types': ['postal_code'],
             'short_name': '91260'
         }],
         'formatted_address': u "5 Avenue de l'Union, 91260 Juvisy-sur-Orge, France",
         'id': 'f63ea1e7a3679ec740d0041fa0166161493ace38',
         'types': ['street_address'],
         'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png'
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at explanations in the following issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823492

Answer (score 0):

as explained here: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#id-overview

you could have 2 types of places_id, one shorter staring with Ch like:

```
ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0
```

and a longer like the one you are using starting with E like:

```
EisxMyBNYXJrZXQgU3RyZWV0LCBXaWxtaW5ndG9uLCBOQyAyODQwMSwgVVNB
```

to summarize it, when is the longer one that means that is interpolated, that means that google try to guess(calculate) where the address is. My point with this is that the shorter one is more accurate and the longer one not very viable.

Should I suggest reporting this as a bug in the correct API in the Issue Tracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com

Happy coding :)